# Losing Data in NSMutableArray Storing Objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'll try and keep this simple.

```
.h

NSMutableArray *allEventsData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *allEventsData;

.m


-(void) test {  
        DAL *db = [[DAL alloc] init]

        self.allEventsData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[db readUniversityEvents]];

        //to test

        for(int i = 0; i < [allEventsData count]; i++) {
           UniversityEvents *obj = (UniversityEvents*)[self.allEventsData objectAtIndex:i];
           NSLog(@"%@", obj.eventId);

        }
}
```

Now that works just fine, however the second this void method is left, I can never access it again, the count property shows that there are still the same amount of records, however if I try the for loop, it will just break out and I'll get Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

I'm being a little vague, but I'm hoping for some suggestions as to why this happens.

Thanks

PS Had to type than manually, so please ignore possible spelling errors.

Edit: Just to clarify, I'm storing an array of objects within a new array, could it be that allEventsData is simply pointing to those objects and not retaining a copy? That would explain the bad access exception

**EDIT 2:**

FYI due to my suspicions above, I also tried the following, however I get SIGABRT exception, currently looking into a solution

```
self.allEventsData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[db readUniversityEvent] copyItems:YES];
```

Log:

```
-[UniversityEvents copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdd17f50
2012-01-16 12:13:17.789 sqliteDemo[1211:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UniversityEvents copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdd17f50'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00f905a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x010e4313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00f920bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f01966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00f01522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00ef0dca -[NSObject(NSObject) copy] + 42
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00f8bff2 -[NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:] + 290
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00ef3e33 -[NSArray initWithArray:copyItems:] + 99
    8   sqliteDemo                          0x000030f4 -[sqliteDemoViewController displayData] + 242
    9   sqliteDemo                          0x00002e30 -[sqliteDemoViewController updateData] + 427
    10  UIKit                               0x003e64fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    11  UIKit                               0x005f8cc3 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 156
    12  UIKit                               0x003e64fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    13  UIKit                               0x00476799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
```

UniversityEvents (this is the object which is being stored within the class)
.h

```
@interface UniversityEvents : NSObject {

}


@property (assign) NSString * eventID;
@property (retain) NSString * title;
@property (retain) NSString * url;
@property (retain) NSString * category;
@property (retain) NSString * date;
@property (retain) NSString * startTime;
@property (retain) NSString * endTime;
@property (retain) NSString * department;
@property (retain) NSString * location;
@property (retain) NSString * description;
//@property (assign) NSInteger * attending;

-(id) initWithData :(NSString *) _eventID :(NSString *) _title :(NSString *)_url :(NSString *)_category :(NSString *)_date
                   :(NSString *)_startTime :(NSString *) _endTime :(NSString *)_department :(NSString *)_location
                   :(NSString *) _description;

@end
```

.m
    @synthesize eventID , title,url,category,date,startTime,endTime,department,location,description;

```
-(id) initWithData :(NSString *) _eventID :(NSString *) _title :(NSString *)_url :(NSString *)_category :(NSString *)_date
                   :(NSString *)_startTime :(NSString *) _endTime :(NSString *)_department :(NSString *)_location
                   :(NSString *) _description 
{

    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.eventID = _eventID;
        self.title = _title;
        self.url = _url;
        self.category = _category;
        self.date = _date;
        self.startTime = _startTime;
        self.endTime = _endTime;
        self.department = _department;
        self.location = _location;
        self.description = _description;
        //self.attending = _attending;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: At which line you are getting "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"? i Think your array get deallocated in your code before you access this second time.

Comment: Edit Scheme > Diagnostics > Enable Zombie Objects - it will help you determine which object is being badly accessed.

Comment: Use self.allEventsData.count instead of allEventsData.count

Comment: @iphonedev23 I get it pretty much anytime I try to access the object, or do anything with it. I too feel it's being deallocated, need to do some more reading up.

Comment: @bandejapaisa I'm using Xcode 3.1, it doesn't appear to have that option sadly

Comment: @Marvin tried both, just get the bad access exception

Comment: Well on Xcode 3.1, add the environment variable NSZombieEnabled YES - it does the same thing. I've forgotten exactly where this is on 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
@property (assign) NSString * eventID;
```

to

```
@property (retain) NSString * eventID;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `[allEventsData count]` (accessing the ivar) and `self.allEventsData` (access the property). Also, did you log each `UniversityEvents` element ? If one of them is nil you can't access its `eventId` property. We might need more code, maybe from the method `readUniversityEvents`

Comment: Nice catch, just tried with .self and get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS as mentioned above, I'll try to post some more code shortly

Comment: You're update is because you use `copyItems:YES` but don't implement `copyWithZone` in your `UniversityEvents`. Before doing the `copyItem`, can you show use the stacktrace/error message/line that breaks ?

Comment: I've implemented the copyWithZone now, I'm just getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS on any line of code that tries accessing the array for example

NSLog(@"%@", [self.allEventsData count] or retrieving an object etc etc

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", [self.allEventsData count]) will crash because count returns in NSUInteger and you are asking NSLog to output an object. What you need to output is NSLog(@"%i", [self.allEventsData count])

Comment: yeah that was me being sloppy